# Apache Pig script output file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

why all Apache pig transformation scripts not producing part-r-00000 output? few transformations producing part-r-00000 and few transformations producing part-m-00000 output. what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting. Please add a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mapper outputs will be part-m-00000 and reducer outputs will be part-r-00000. So if last stage of your pig script has mapper only jobs then you can expect part-m-I0000 else part-r-0000.